Chainlink Functions: How can I get array from my JS file and use it in the contract?
I am trying to use Chainlink Functions, and I have a requirement to actually get values in array form from my JS file and input it in the contract using functions. I have created this code:
// Define the array of uint256 values to be returned
const uint256Array = [1, 2, 3];
    
// Function to encode a uint256 value to a 32-byte Uint8Array
function encodeUint256(value) {
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(32); // Allocate a 32-byte buffer
    const valueBigInt = BigInt(value);
    
    // Write the value as a big-endian 256-bit integer
    for (let i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        buffer[i] = Number(valueBigInt & BigInt(0xff));
        valueBigInt >>= BigInt(8);
    }
    return buffer;
}

// Allocate a buffer large enough to hold all the elements (each uint256 is 32 bytes)
const bufferLength = uint256Array.length * 32;
const buffer = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

// Write each encoded element into the buffer at the correct offset
for (let i = 0; i < uint256Array.length; i++) {
    const encodedElement = encodeUint256(uint256Array[i]);
    buffer.set(encodedElement, i * 32);
}

// Return the encoded array as the function result
return buffer;

This function is returning the correct bytes value as expected.
Smart Contract:
function fulfillRequest(
    bytes32 requestId,
    bytes memory response,
    bytes memory err
) internal override {
    s_lastError = err;

    if (response.length > 0) {
        uint256[] memory array = abi.decode(response, (uint256[]));

        influencerShare[1] = array;
    }
}

Now I am sure my code is not right. How can I fetch the array from the functions, and use it in my contract? Any help would be good.

In your Functions script, you've to return the hex representation of the buffer value. You can use ethers library to achieve that with ease, and test the same using @chainlink/functions-toolkit package.
Here's the minimal setup to test the same:
source.js
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.12.1');
const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();
const uint256Array = [1, 2, 3];
const encoded = abiCoder.encode(['uint256[]'], [uint256Array]);
return ethers.getBytes(encoded);

request-config.js
const fs = require("fs");

const { Location, ReturnType, CodeLanguage } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");

const requestConfig = {
    source: fs.readFileSync("./source.js").toString(),
    codeLocation: Location.Inline,
    secrets: {},
    args: [],
    codeLanguage: CodeLanguage.JavaScript,
    expectedReturnType: ReturnType.bytes,
    secretsURLs: [],
}

module.exports = requestConfig;

simulate-script.js
const { simulateScript } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");
const requestConfig = require('./request-config');

async function main() {
    const { responseBytesHexstring, capturedTerminalOutput, errorString } = await simulateScript(requestConfig);

    console.log('Response:', responseBytesHexstring);
    console.log('Error:', errorString)
    console.log('Terminal Output:', capturedTerminalOutput);
}

main();

Now, you can execute the simulate-script.js:
$ node simulate-script.js

Output:

So, the value of responseBytesHexstring is:
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003

And, the same can be decoded to get the corresponding uint256 array in the contract. Here's the minimal contract to showcase the decoding:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract DecodeArray {
    function decode(bytes memory encodedArray) external pure returns (uint256[] memory)  {
        return abi.decode(encodedArray, (uint256[]));
    }
}

Output:


And, here's the minimal integrated FunctionsConsumer contract (hardcoded for Polygon Amoy network):
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";

/**
 * @title FunctionsConsumer
 * @dev This contract uses hardcoded values and should not be used in production.
 */
contract FunctionsConsumer is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;

    // State variables to store the last request ID, response and error
    bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
    bytes public s_lastResponse;
    uint256[] public s_decodedArray;
    bytes public s_lastError;

    error UnexpectedRequestID(bytes32 requestId);

    // Event to log responses
    event Response(bytes32 indexed requestId, bytes response, bytes err);

    // Router address - Hardcoded for Polygon Amoy
    address router = 0xC22a79eBA640940ABB6dF0f7982cc119578E11De;

    // JavaScript source code
    string source =
        "const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.12.1');"
        "const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();"
        "const uint256Array = [1, 2, 3];"
        "const encoded = abiCoder.encode(['uint256[]'], [uint256Array]);"
        "return ethers.getBytes(encoded);";

    // Callback gas limit
    uint32 gasLimit = 300_000;

    // donID - Hardcoded for Polygon Amoy
    bytes32 donID =
        0x66756e2d706f6c79676f6e2d616d6f792d310000000000000000000000000000;

    /**
     * @notice Initializes the contract with the Chainlink router address and sets the contract owner
     */
    constructor() FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {}

    /**
     * @notice Sends an HTTP request for character information
     * @param subscriptionId The ID for the Chainlink subscription
     * @param args The arguments to pass to the HTTP request
     * @return requestId The ID of the request
     */
    function sendRequest(uint64 subscriptionId, string[] calldata args)
        external
        onlyOwner
        returns (bytes32 requestId)
    {
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source); // Initialize the request with JS code
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args); // Set the arguments for the request

        // Send the request and store the request ID
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionId,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Callback function for fulfilling a request
     * @param requestId The ID of the request to fulfill
     * @param response The HTTP response data
     * @param err Any errors from the Functions request
     */
    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId); // Check if request IDs match
        }
        // Update the contract's state variables with the response and any errors
        s_lastResponse = response;
        s_decodedArray = abi.decode(s_lastResponse, (uint256[]));
        s_lastError = err;

        // Emit an event to log the response
        emit Response(requestId, s_lastResponse, s_lastError);
    }
}

Output:





Hey, thanks for the detailed answer. I did try this approach but for some reason didn't work on my end. I found another way, and it is working for now. However, I will try this approach again as it is simpler than mine.

Sure. Let me know how it goes. Happy building!
